# send sms from background thread in blackberry using j2me

Tags: blackberry, java-me

hey i made a lot of search and found some similar types of code.
I tried for gsm

method 1 gives IllegalArgumentException

```
try
{
MessageConnection _mc = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) _mc.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
tm.setPayloadText(smsText);
tm.setAddress("965xxxxxxx");
_mc.send(tm);
_mc.close();
}catch(exception e){}
```

method 2: gives java.lang.error exception

```
  try
    {
    MessageConnection _mc = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
    TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) _mc.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE,
"//9790XXXXXX");
    tm.setPayloadText(text);
    _mc.send(tm);
    _mc.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

I think the problem is with address
i also tried : but no success
+91965xxxxxxx , 
0091965xxxxxxx , 
0965xxxxxxx

How my application works----

i have created 2 applications--

```
1) Application 1 is a background app that is a System module as well as 
    startup application.
2) Another is a uiapplication
```

the background app runs in background.If there comes an incoming call then a flag value is set in persistent object and after checking that value as true the sms is send to that no from whom call is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.Datagram;
import javax.microedition.io.DatagramConnection;
import javax.wireless.messaging.MessageConnection;
import javax.wireless.messaging.TextMessage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.RadioInfo;

public class SendSMS extends Thread {

    private String to;
    private String msg;

    public SendSMS(String to, String msg) {
        this.to = to;
        this.msg = msg;

    }

    public void run() {
        if (RadioInfo.getNetworkType() == RadioInfo.NETWORK_CDMA) {
            DatagramConnection dc = null;
            try {
                dc = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + to);
                byte[] data = msg.getBytes();
                Datagram dg = dc.newDatagram(dc.getMaximumLength());
                dg.setData(data, 0, data.length);
                dc.send(dg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    dc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } else {
            MessageConnection mc = null;
            try {
                mc = (MessageConnection) Connector
                        .open("sms://" + to);
                TextMessage m = (TextMessage) mc
                        .newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
                m.setPayloadText(msg);
                mc.send(m);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    mc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and call like this

```
public void callDisconnected(int callId) {
        final PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);
        final String number = call.getDisplayPhoneNumber();
        SendSMS sendSMS = new SendSMS(number, "message");
        sendSMS.start();
        super.callDisconnected(callId);
    }
```

Comment: hi vivart,your suggestion did not give ant exception but it did not send the message to the number specified by me
.What to do???????????????

Comment: this is a tested code it works fine for me. have you tested on real device?

Comment: ya i tested on the device but msg was not send
i think i should explain u the whole logic in my question.

Comment: hey 1 more thing if i place System.out.println("message sent"); statement between _mc.send(tm); and _mc.close();then statement does not executes

Comment: hey Vivart your refined suggestion throws=====
net.rim.device.api.io.IOCancelledException Exception while sending the message on the simulator

Comment: moreover i found that this exception is generated 3 times

Comment: i made a check that code executes only once but still IOCancelledException exists

Comment: if i am using two simulators and my code with port number, its working fine. I have successfully received sms in 2nd simulator.

Comment: thanks so much vivart..................
ur method worked on the device
I m really thankful to u!!!!

Comment: hey Vivart can u tell me--Does this code works for both gsm and cdma or it only works for gsm mobiles.Sorry i unchecked the ans just to get response from u

Comment: well thank u so much for all your help.i will test it somehow.
Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: usually xx30 model number for blackberry is CDMA. So start any simulator like 8130,8830,etc it will be CDMA.